# MySql: Append one column to another

Tags: mysql, database, merge

I need to append contents of one column in MySql table to another column in same table with a space in between. So,

```
Table:
col_1      col_2
row1c1     row1
row2c1     row2
row3c1     row3
row4c1     row4
```

Needs to change to

```
Changed Table:
col_1      col_2
row1c1     row1c1 row1
row2c1     row2c1 row2
row3c1     row3c1 row3
row4c1     row4c1 row4
```

For entire length of the table.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
update Table set col_2 = concat(col_1, ' ', col_2);
```

Comment: Why is SO making me wait like 15 mins to accept this as ans? I could vote you up but not accept as answer!?

Answer (score 2):

`UPDATE table SET col_2 = CONTACT_WS(' ', col_1, col_2)`

Comment: Jeff's worked, so whats the difference b/w his and yours, besides the obvious change of order? performance?

Comment: I doubt there's anything worth noting between them.  He just posted before I had finished adding my answer, I think!

Comment: Well, i guess it deserves a vote up at the least, so i did, thanks for the effort.